# Выравнивание ширины внешнего div по ширине внутренних

Tags: html, css

```
   Делаю внешнему div свойство display:inline-block;
   внутренним div-ам float:left; width:250px;
```

Пример https://jsfiddle.net/hejvkt/2bL86hpb/

Проблема: если внутренние дивы помещаются в одну строку, то все работает как нужно и граница внешнего дива = границе внутреннего. Если же ширины для внутренних дивов не хватает и они перескакивают во вторую линию, то внешний див становится просто по ширине 100%.

Comment: ??? В примере внешний див не меняется... Тут у меня две идеи - либо ставить `overflow` на скроллинг, либо переходить к относительным ширинам (%) внутренних блоков

Comment: не понял как тут может влиять overflow? В моем примере, если например удалить 2 дива из 4 четырех, то ширина внешнего дива выравняется по границе внутреннего.https://yadi.sk/i/Rtyu-n543GVU3D

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Вам надо как в примере (по ссылке) или не так? Если не так - то как? Если надо, чтобы внешний див менял размер - не задавайте ему ширины, используйте таблицу, оверфлоу...

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы граница внешнего div смещалась в зависимости от того переходят внутренние дивы на новую строку или нет. https://yadi.sk/i/k_TSFfLM3GVUbv

Comment: Если элементы не вмещаются - на это есть свойство `overflow`. Детали - в Гугле. Но они не могут "не вмещаться" если у внешнего дива нет ширины. Не задавайте ее...

Comment: аcсоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104665/fit-div-width-to-inline-block-children-unknown-number-of-divs-per-row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не нашел метода только на CSS, вот пример с использованием JavaScript.

```js
var a = document.getElementById('a');
a.style.display = 'inline';
a.style.width = a.getBoundingClientRect().width + 'px';
a.style.display = '';
```

```css
#a {
  background-color: gray;
}
.b {
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
  <div class="b"></div>
</div>
```

[Решение отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31104665/fit-div-width-to-inline-block-children-unknown-number-of-divs-per-row)

Comment: мда уж, вроде бы тривиальная задача для разметки.

Comment: Мораль: Есть вещи, которые надо знать, что так лучше не делать

Comment: К сожалению не совсем подойдет мне такое решение, придется добавлять еще обработчик на изменение размеров окна и пересчитывать ширину через него :). Смысл в том что у меня 4-ые дива в ряд и они должны перескакивать на другие строчки при уменьшении размера окна браузера. По другому я даже не знаю как это сделать.